# How to use select statement insert first row of dummy dash value with 2 table combination

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
table_A
no   desciption         
1     Apple
2     orange
3     banana
4     kiwi
5     papaya

table_B
no     price      mydate
1      10.00      20210801
2       8.00      20210802
3       5.00      20210803
4      12.00      20210804
5       4.00      20210805
```

Hi, I try to use this SQL and union all but show an error.

```
select '-' a.description, '-' b.price from dual union all select a.description,sum(b.price) from table_A a, table_B b where a.no=b.no and b.mydate='20210801' group by a.description;

ORA-00923 : FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I need result

```
a.description    sum(b.price)
   -                  -       <-----dummy dash always on first row
   Apple            10.00
```

Anyone help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no aliases `a` and `b` in your first part of `union all`, so just remove `a.` and `b.`
2. Don't use implicit conversion from char literals to date, use literal dates instead:

```sql
select '-' as description, '-' as price from dual 
union all 
select a.description,to_char(sum(b.price))
from 
    table_A a
    join table_B b 
        on a.no=b.no
where b.mydate=date'2021-08-01' 
group by a.description;
```

Comment: Hi Sayan, seem like your SQL is work! but if I add in one more table for query, can I just add another JOIN and ON ?

Comment: @Hoongwaikong please describe what do you mean by "add one more table"?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to

- use a subquery
- it contains additional `rn` column (where `1` means that those values will represent "row number 1" in the result)
- apply `to_char` function to `sum(b.price)` because - with `union` - queries have to match in number of columns and their datatypes

So:

```
  SELECT description, price
    FROM (SELECT 1 rn, '-' description, '-' price FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 rn, a.description, TO_CHAR (SUM (b.price))
              FROM table_A a, table_B b
             WHERE     a.no = b.no
                   AND b.mydate = '20210801'
          GROUP BY a.description)
ORDER BY rn
```

which - applied to your sample data - returns

```
DESCRIPTION     PRICE
--------------- ----------------------------------------
-               -
apple           10
```

---

Note that:

- `mydate` should be a true `date` datatype column; don't use *strings* because nothing prevents you from entering e.g. `2f$8-23` into a `varchar2` column, and that certainly isn't a valid date value
- try to switch to `join`s; leave `where` clause for *conditions* data should meet in order to be returned

Something like this:

```
from table_a a join table_b b on a.no = b.no   --> JOIN
where b.mydate = date '2021-08-01'             --> MYDATE being DATE datatype
```